# Find presorted array in random array

Tags: arrays

I wonder there is no problem-solution exist even at google. So first let me define problem and then I will define my algorithm too. If you have a better solution you can tell.

```
Problem: 
Find pre-sorted array in random array for example if 
Array = {4, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 15, 12, 13}
output = {4, 5, 7, 9, 15}
```

Comment: you only care for "presorted" starting in the first element? because if not this is much more complicated

Comment: but in this way we can compute for each ith element. I know for first element it is very easy but it should be on google or any platform where understanding is the priority for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

```
Algorithm :
1 : take the ith/first element from the array
2 : for each i+1
3 : if (Array[i]<Array[i+1])
4 : OutArray[i]=Array[i+1]
5 : else
6 : No element found
```